# Python script to loop for files in subdirectories in order to change text and extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]I'm trying to loop through files in multiple subdirectories in order to :
1- Add some text inside the files (ending with .ext)
2- Change the extension  of each file from .ext to .ext2

The script works fine when I have only one subdir in the main directory, but when I try to run the script on multiple subdirs it says:
line 8, in 
with open(name, "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "here the name of the subdir"

```
import os

directory = 'C:\\Users\\folder\\subfolders'

for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".ext")):
            with open(name, "r") as f:
                XMLContent = f.readlines()
            XMLContent.insert(6, '<XMLFormat>\n')
            XMLContent.insert(40, '\n</XMLFormat>')

            with open(name, "w") as f:
                XMLContent = "".join(XMLContent)
                f.write(XMLContent)
            os.rename(os.path.join(dir, name), os.path.join(dir, name[:name.index('.ext')] +".ext1"))
```

Above is a screenshot of the sub dirs I have in the folder (1.Modified).

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of the subfolders and files? And if you explain a bit more about the logic in your code so we can help you quickly!!

Answer (score 1):

I've also created a new folder called **all** and put in it three folders and for each folder, I've created 2 files of **.ext** type.

So, I was able to write inside each file of them and change its name as well.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/ghaith/Desktop/test/all"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.ext'):
            path = root + '/' + file

            with open(path, "r") as f:
                content = f.readlines()

            content.insert(1, '<XMLFormat>\n')
            content.insert(3, '\n</XMLFormat>')

            with open(path, "w") as f:
                content = "".join(content)
                f.write(content)

            os.rename(path, path+'2')
```

> Output:
>
> < XMLFormat >
>
> < /XMLFormat >

Comment: Thank you Mohamad for your answer, in fact Im trying to add text in a specific index of the file for example in the line 7 of the file I want to add a tag like this <test> and close the tag </test> at the last line of the file thats why I was using the insert (index , value) method

Comment: Ok got it, but does the `.ext` support `XML` format?

Comment: It was just for the sake of example but the real file is technically the same format so it does support it of course. My first script works really fine when there is only one sub directory but when I have multiple sub-directories in the folder the script starts showing errors just like I mentioned in the post above.

Comment: @7chour Please try the code right now. I got it `<XMLFormat> </XMLFormat>` placed one the 1 and 3 lines in all files!

Comment: This is exactly what I have done yesterday after the first code you submitted, the path line in the code was the key to solve the issue thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the directory to open the file

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, name), "r") as f:
```

But, I think the best way is use the `os.listdir()` to loop in the directory

```
for item in os.listdir(directory):
    if item.endswith(".ext"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, item), "r") as r:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried them both but neither of them worked for me. Im getting : = Restart and python file path.

Comment: Sorry, I just see your printscreen now, you have directories, then you need to access them  or you need put the directory name on path. Please, share the directory tree

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do the issue is that when I use the script when I have only 1 sub directory it works fine but when I put other subdirectories it won't.